# Selecting the time with miliseconds with sed command from log file

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I'm new to sed command functionalities and i've a log file such as :

```
2014-09-16 18:26:59,300 INFO auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - performing commit
2014-09-16 18:26:59,301 DEBUG auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - closing all statements
2014-09-16 18:26:59,301 INFO auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [SQLPool] - returning connection to pool ecls
2014-09-16 18:26:59,301 DEBUG auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - closing all statements
2014-09-16 18:26:59,301 DEBUG auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [SQLPool] - 10 total, 5 available, 5 used.
2014-09-16 18:26:59,824 DEBUG auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [SQLPool] - retrieved connection from pool ecls
2014-09-16 18:26:59,824 DEBUG auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [SQLPool] - 10 total, 4 available, 6 used.
2014-09-16 18:26:59,824 DEBUG auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [Statement] - SELECT COUNT(T.sl_tr_id) FROM sl_versionset, sl_cmsra_tree T, sl_cmsra_obj, sl_cmsra_common WHERE t.sl_obj_id=sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_id
AND sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_deleted_flag=0
AND sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_id = sl_cmsra_common.sl_obj_id
AND sl_cmsra_common.misc like '%modified=false%'
AND sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_objtyp_id in (121,120,113,112,111,110)
AND t.sl_tr_deleted_flag=0
AND (sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_last_changed_by='auerm' 
OR sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_created_by='auerm') AND 
sl_versionset.sl_obj_id (+)= sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_id AND (
-- ['WIP'] 
sl_versionset.sl_vs_state <> 'Deprecated' AND 
sl_versionset.sl_vs_next is null
OR T.sl_tr_container_flag = 1)
2014-09-16 18:26:59,967 INFO auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - performing commit
2014-09-16 18:26:59,967 DEBUG auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - closing all statements
2014-09-16 18:26:59,967 INFO auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [SQLPool] - returning connection to pool ecls
2014-09-16 18:26:59,968 DEBUG auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - closing all statements
2014-09-16 18:26:59,968 DEBUG auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [SQLPool] - 10 total, 5 available, 5 used.
2014-09-16 18:27:00,479 DEBUG auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [SQLPool] - retrieved connection from pool ecls
2014-09-16 18:27:00,479 DEBUG auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [SQLPool] - 10 total, 4 available, 6 used.
2014-09-16 18:27:00,479 DEBUG auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [Statement] - SELECT COUNT(T.sl_tr_id) FROM sl_versionset, sl_cmsra_tree T, sl_cmsra_obj, sl_cmsra_tlorder TLO WHERE t.sl_obj_id=sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_id
AND 
(sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_WFST_ID=10 OR
 sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_WFST_ID=30 OR
 sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_WFST_ID=40 )
AND sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_objtyp_id=71
AND sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_deleted_flag=0
AND t.sl_tr_deleted_flag=0
and tlo.sl_obj_id=sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_id
and tlo.orderer = 'auerm' AND 
sl_versionset.sl_obj_id (+)= sl_cmsra_obj.sl_obj_id AND (
-- ['WIP'] 
sl_versionset.sl_vs_state <> 'Deprecated' AND 
sl_versionset.sl_vs_next is null
OR T.sl_tr_container_flag = 1)
2014-09-16 18:27:00,482 INFO auerm@10.33.165.102-131 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - performing commit
```

And I'm wanna get just the second block of these logs to compute with time like get all lines according to regular expression :

```
/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2}-)\w+ ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}),([0-9]{3})/mg
```

(I think this /mg means multiline and global)

when i tested it on the regex testers it fits my expectations but when i used it on the command like :

`cat abc.log | sed '/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2}-)\w+ ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}),([0-9]{3})/mg` it says  it is unrecognized command on regex.

When i try to awk '{print $2}' it returns some line according to my request but after that i'm facing with in somewhere it has many fields, i think these sql commands makes it bad. The command i'm trying is :

```
cat abc.log | sed -n '/^2014-09-16/p' | awk '{print $2}'
```

So i need to take just the line starting with time without sql command. Could you please help me on this case ?

Edit : According to answers i am adding another 80 lines of log file because as a command i couldn't do it :

```
2014-09-22 08:16:28,042 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-181 [PreparedStatement] - SELECT link_id, creation_date, created_by, category_id, show, actuate, internal_flag FROM sl_link WHERE deleted_flag = 0 AND link_id IN ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )  -- [1084426, 1084366, 1084461, 1084481, 1149527, 1084484, 1084449, 1084423, 1084347, 1084469, 1084487, 1084420, 1084360, 1084363, 1084385, 1085563, 1084382, 1085560, 1085566, 1084357, 1084417, 1084433, 1084414, 1084474, 1084438, 1084411, 1084350, 1084477, 1084455, 1084392, 1084376, 1084395, 1084398, 1085551, 1084405, 1085557, 1084429, 1085554, 1084401, 1084379]
2014-09-22 08:16:28,045 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-181 [PreparedStatement] - SELECT anchor_id, link_id, creation_date, created_by, pending_flag, pending_since, validated_date, resource_type, resource_uri, resource_info, resource_id, pointer_type, pointer_info, pointer, anchor_syntax, pp_id, sequence  FROM sl_source_anchor WHERE deleted_flag = 0 and link_id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) ORDER BY link_id, sequence -- [1084426, 1084366, 1084461, 1084481, 1149527, 1084484, 1084449, 1084423, 1084347, 1084469, 1084487, 1084420, 1084360, 1084363, 1084385, 1085563, 1084382, 1085560, 1085566, 1084357, 1084417, 1084433, 1084414, 1084474, 1084438, 1084411, 1084350, 1084477, 1084455, 1084392, 1084376, 1084395, 1084398, 1085551, 1084405, 1085557, 1084429, 1085554, 1084401, 1084379]
2014-09-22 08:16:28,076 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-181 [PreparedStatement] - SELECT anchor_id, link_id, creation_date, created_by, pending_flag, pending_since, validated_date, resource_type, resource_uri, resource_info, resource_id, pointer_type, pointer_info, pointer, anchor_syntax, pp_id, sequence  FROM sl_target_anchor WHERE deleted_flag = 0 and link_id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) ORDER BY link_id, sequence -- [1084426, 1084366, 1084461, 1084481, 1149527, 1084484, 1084449, 1084423, 1084347, 1084469, 1084487, 1084420, 1084360, 1084363, 1084385, 1085563, 1084382, 1085560, 1085566, 1084357, 1084417, 1084433, 1084414, 1084474, 1084438, 1084411, 1084350, 1084477, 1084455, 1084392, 1084376, 1084395, 1084398, 1085551, 1084405, 1085557, 1084429, 1085554, 1084401, 1084379]
2014-09-22 08:16:28,082 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-181 [PreparedStatement] - SELECT DISTINCT sl_link.link_id, sl_source_anchor.anchor_id, sl_target_anchor.anchor_id FROM sl_link, sl_target_anchor, sl_CMSRA_tree TARGET_ALIAS_3, sl_versionset TARGET_ALIAS_2, sl_source_anchor WHERE sl_link.deleted_flag = 0 AND sl_link.pending = 0 AND 
TARGET_ALIAS_2.sl_obj_id (+) = sl_target_anchor.resource_id AND TARGET_ALIAS_3.sl_obj_id = sl_target_anchor.resource_id AND ((
-- ['WIP'] 
TARGET_ALIAS_2.sl_vs_state <> 'Deprecated' AND 
TARGET_ALIAS_2.sl_vs_next is null
) OR sl_target_anchor.resource_id IS NULL OR TARGET_ALIAS_3.sl_tr_container_flag = 1) AND sl_source_anchor.resource_uri IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) AND sl_source_anchor.pending_flag = 0 AND sl_source_anchor.link_id=sl_link.link_id AND sl_source_anchor.deleted_flag = 0 AND sl_target_anchor.pending_flag = 0 AND sl_target_anchor.link_id=sl_link.link_id AND sl_target_anchor.deleted_flag = 0 ORDER BY 1 -- [ecls:io:ecls/3/1015555, ecls:io:ecls/3/991291, ecls:io:ecls/3/772431, ecls:io:ecls/3/932498, ecls:io:ecls/3/580886, ecls:io:ecls/3/1127746, ecls:io:ecls/3/985308, ecls:io:ecls/3/935446, ecls:io:ecls/3/934784, ecls:io:ecls/3/995336, ecls:io:ecls/3/1153511, ecls:io:ecls/3/1155750, ecls:io:ecls/3/994629, ecls:io:ecls/3/936319, ecls:io:ecls/3/932681, ecls:io:ecls/3/993620, ecls:io:ecls/3/932324, ecls:io:ecls/3/581503, ecls:io:ecls/3/1013902, ecls:io:ecls/3/1146016, ecls:io:ecls/3/534916, ecls:io:ecls/3/1040315, ecls:io:ecls/3/932867, ecls:io:ecls/3/993356, ecls:io:ecls/3/1038906, ecls:io:ecls/3/1041365, ecls:io:ecls/3/581482, ecls:io:ecls/3/581191, ecls:io:ecls/3/1041362, ecls:io:ecls/3/985334, ecls:io:ecls/3/991459, ecls:io:ecls/3/931958, ecls:io:ecls/3/864357, ecls:io:ecls/3/935174, ecls:io:ecls/3/847145, ecls:io:ecls/3/994638, ecls:io:ecls/3/1038862, ecls:io:ecls/3/989179, ecls:io:ecls/3/1127956, ecls:io:ecls/3/1012113]
2014-09-22 08:16:28,363 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-181 [PreparedStatement] - SELECT link_id, creation_date, created_by, category_id, show, actuate, internal_flag FROM sl_link WHERE deleted_flag = 0 AND link_id IN ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )  -- [575423, 581411, 985352, 991821, 575427, 991825, 864400, 991829, 935668, 903219, 903192, 811178, 985159, 811172, 575431, 985348, 1147467, 575435, 1154228, 575439, 581405, 1155847, 581408, 993626, 580864, 1149173, 580868, 991578, 802877, 581388, 580872, 580860, 802834, 993138, 1012114, 811291, 1012117, 993610, 1014008, 802760, 779242, 811196, 1014004, 802764, 991279, 575447, 935680, 935684, 724502, 575443, 903187, 1012123, 985341, 985345, 935449, 994647, 575419, 935676, 811181, 724498, 1154583, 1154587, 864397, 811204, 811188, 864394, 989232, 580893, 935672, 578642, 1012120]
2014-09-22 08:16:28,367 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-181 [PreparedStatement] - SELECT anchor_id, link_id, creation_date, created_by, pending_flag, pending_since, validated_date, resource_type, resource_uri, resource_info, resource_id, pointer_type, pointer_info, pointer, anchor_syntax, pp_id, sequence  FROM sl_source_anchor WHERE deleted_flag = 0 and link_id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) ORDER BY link_id, sequence -- [575423, 581411, 985352, 991821, 575427, 991825, 864400, 991829, 935668, 903219, 903192, 811178, 985159, 811172, 575431, 985348, 1147467, 575435, 1154228, 575439, 581405, 1155847, 581408, 993626, 580864, 1149173, 580868, 991578, 802877, 581388, 580872, 580860, 802834, 993138, 1012114, 811291, 1012117, 993610, 1014008, 802760, 779242, 811196, 1014004, 802764, 991279, 575447, 935680, 935684, 724502, 575443, 903187, 1012123, 985341, 985345, 935449, 994647, 575419, 935676, 811181, 724498, 1154583, 1154587, 864397, 811204, 811188, 864394, 989232, 580893, 935672, 578642, 1012120]
2014-09-22 08:16:28,448 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-181 [PreparedStatement] - SELECT anchor_id, link_id, creation_date, created_by, pending_flag, pending_since, validated_date, resource_type, resource_uri, resource_info, resource_id, pointer_type, pointer_info, pointer, anchor_syntax, pp_id, sequence  FROM sl_target_anchor WHERE deleted_flag = 0 and link_id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) ORDER BY link_id, sequence -- [575423, 581411, 985352, 991821, 575427, 991825, 864400, 991829, 935668, 903219, 903192, 811178, 985159, 811172, 575431, 985348, 1147467, 575435, 1154228, 575439, 581405, 1155847, 581408, 993626, 580864, 1149173, 580868, 991578, 802877, 581388, 580872, 580860, 802834, 993138, 1012114, 811291, 1012117, 993610, 1014008, 802760, 779242, 811196, 1014004, 802764, 991279, 575447, 935680, 935684, 724502, 575443, 903187, 1012123, 985341, 985345, 935449, 994647, 575419, 935676, 811181, 724498, 1154583, 1154587, 864397, 811204, 811188, 864394, 989232, 580893, 935672, 578642, 1012120]
2014-09-22 08:16:28,501 INFO gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-181 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - performing commit
2014-09-22 08:16:28,502 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-181 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - closing all statements
2014-09-22 08:16:28,502 INFO gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-181 [SQLPool] - returning connection to pool ecls
2014-09-22 08:16:28,502 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-181 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - closing all statements
2014-09-22 08:16:28,502 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-181 [SQLPool] - 10 total, 5 available, 5 used.
2014-09-22 08:16:28,609 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-604 [SQLPool] - retrieved connection from pool ecls
2014-09-22 08:16:28,609 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-604 [SQLPool] - 10 total, 4 available, 6 used.
2014-09-22 08:16:28,610 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-604 [Statement] - SELECT sl_obj_display_title, sl_obj_created_date, sl_obj_created_by, sl_obj_last_changed_date, sl_obj_last_changed_by, sl_obj_check_out_flag, sl_obj_check_out_date, sl_obj_check_out_by, sl_obj_objtyp_id, sl_obj_content_size, sl_obj_link_indicator, sl_obj_content_format, sl_obj_content_lang, sl_obj_content_charset, sl_obj_wfst_id, sl_obj_wfst_changed_by, sl_obj_wfst_changed_date, sl_obj_content_flag, O.sl_obj_id FROM SL_CMSRA_OBJ O, SL_CMSRA_CONTENT C WHERE C.sl_obj_id = O.sl_obj_id AND sl_obj_deleted_flag = 0 AND O.sl_obj_id IN (935446, 1012113, 935174, 1040315, 985334, 994629, 994638, 1127956, 1146016, 1153511, 580886, 581482, 993356, 864357, 1013902, 995336, 993620, 1155750, 989179, 1149480, 1041365, 1127746)
2014-09-22 08:16:28,686 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-604 [PreparedStatement] - (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 1012113 AND elm_id IN ('SL994263', 'SL994267', 'SL992506', 'SL781497')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 935446 AND elm_id IN ('SL935448')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 935174 AND elm_id IN ('SL935671', 'SL935675', 'SL935679', 'SL935667', 'SL935683')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 1040315 AND elm_id IN ('SL772364', 'SL802773', 'SL802763')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 985334 AND elm_id IN ('SL935420', 'SL935428', 'SL935432', 'SL936271', 'SL993137')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 994629 AND elm_id IN ('SL991278')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 994638 AND elm_id IN ('SL989231')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 1127956 AND elm_id IN ('SL724501', 'SL575359', 'SL575355', 'SL575418', 'SL581387', 'SL575363', 'SL724497', 'SL575426', 'SL575422', 'SL575434', 'SL575438', 'SL575430', 'SL575446', 'SL575442')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 1146016 AND elm_id IN ('SL1147466', 'SL1149171')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 1153511 AND elm_id IN ('SL802868', 'SL802863', 'SL779533', 'SL811203', 'SL802876', 'SL1154227', 'SL1154586', 'SL1154582', 'SL777176', 'SL811171', 'SL811195')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 580886 AND elm_id IN ('SL534986')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 993356 AND elm_id IN ('SL993609')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 581482 AND elm_id IN ('SL575387')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 864357 AND elm_id IN ('SL772645', 'SL772644', 'SL772643', 'SL903191')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 1013902 AND elm_id IN ('SL991828', 'SL991820', 'SL991824', 'SL991816', 'SL991577', 'SL1014003')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 995336 AND elm_id IN ('SL985158')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 993620 AND elm_id IN ('SL993609')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 1155750 AND elm_id IN ('SL1155845')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 989179 AND elm_id IN ('SL989231')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 1149480 AND elm_id IN ('SL995205', 'SL1015547', 'SL995208', 'SL995206', 'SL995207', 'SL1015516', 'SL1015517', 'SL574870', 'SL1015525', 'SL1015524', 'SL996783', 'SL1149526', 'SL1015519', 'SL1085550', 'SL1012105', 'SL1012102', 'SL1085547', 'SL535484', 'SL1085546', 'SL535485', 'SL1085545', 'SL535482', 'SL535483', 'SL1085549', 'SL535486', 'SL1085548', 'SL500106', 'SL500105', 'SL500109', 'SL500108', 'SL500107', 'SL1015373', 'SL1015565', 'SL995210', 'SL995216', 'SL995215', 'SL540243', 'SL540244', 'SL995213', 'SL540245')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 1041365 AND elm_id IN ('SL779241')) UNION (SELECT obj_id, elm_id, elm_name, pre_order, post_order FROM  SL_ID_ELEMENTS WHERE obj_id = 1127746 AND elm_id IN ('SL534972', 'SL534973', 'SL534974', 'SL534975')) ORDER BY obj_id, pre_order -- []
2014-09-22 08:16:28,827 INFO gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-604 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - performing commit
2014-09-22 08:16:28,827 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-604 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - closing all statements
2014-09-22 08:16:28,827 INFO gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-604 [SQLPool] - returning connection to pool ecls
2014-09-22 08:16:28,828 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-604 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - closing all statements
2014-09-22 08:16:28,828 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-604 [SQLPool] - 10 total, 5 available, 5 used.
2014-09-22 08:16:28,870 DEBUG canlier@10.176.24.136-131 [SQLPool] - retrieved connection from pool ecls
2014-09-22 08:16:28,870 DEBUG canlier@10.176.24.136-131 [SQLPool] - 10 total, 4 available, 6 used.
2014-09-22 08:16:28,871 DEBUG canlier@10.176.24.136-131 [PreparedStatement] - SELECT sl_tr_display_title, sl_obj_created_date, sl_obj_created_by, sl_tr_sortkey, sl_tr_parent, sl_tr_predecessor, sl_tr_successor, sl_tr_level, sl_tr_path, sl_tr_container_flag, sl_tr_container_type, T.sl_obj_id, sl_tr_splitnode_flag, sl_tr_original_flag FROM SL_CMSRA_TREE T, SL_CMSRA_OBJ O WHERE T.sl_tr_id = ? AND T.sl_obj_id = O.sl_obj_id AND T.sl_tr_deleted_flag = 0 -- [1119674]
2014-09-22 08:16:28,873 INFO canlier@10.176.24.136-131 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - performing rollback
2014-09-22 08:16:28,874 DEBUG canlier@10.176.24.136-131 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - closing all statements
2014-09-22 08:16:28,874 INFO canlier@10.176.24.136-131 [SQLPool] - returning connection to pool ecls
2014-09-22 08:16:28,875 DEBUG canlier@10.176.24.136-131 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - closing all statements
2014-09-22 08:16:28,875 DEBUG canlier@10.176.24.136-131 [SQLPool] - 10 total, 5 available, 5 used.
2014-09-22 08:16:28,875 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-603 [SQLPool] - retrieved connection from pool ecls
2014-09-22 08:16:28,876 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-603 [SQLPool] - 10 total, 4 available, 6 used.
2014-09-22 08:16:28,876 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-603 [Statement] - SELECT sl_obj_display_title, sl_obj_created_date, sl_obj_created_by, sl_obj_last_changed_date, sl_obj_last_changed_by, sl_obj_check_out_flag, sl_obj_check_out_date, sl_obj_check_out_by, sl_obj_objtyp_id, sl_obj_content_size, sl_obj_link_indicator, sl_obj_content_format, sl_obj_content_lang, sl_obj_content_charset, sl_obj_wfst_id, sl_obj_wfst_changed_by, sl_obj_wfst_changed_date, sl_obj_content_flag, O.sl_obj_id FROM SL_CMSRA_OBJ O, SL_CMSRA_CONTENT C WHERE C.sl_obj_id = O.sl_obj_id AND sl_obj_deleted_flag = 0 AND O.sl_obj_id IN (985308, 802837, 1036421, 935577, 1040315, 994638, 935574, 991465, 989363, 772431, 989229, 989345, 802841, 992489, 1013935, 1015555, 985153, 777138, 994625, 994072, 994629, 935583, 989374, 992317, 935568, 993352, 935580, 995336, 993620, 989179, 802757, 989356)
2014-09-22 08:16:28,922 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-603 [Statement] - SELECT T.sl_tr_id, T.sl_obj_id FROM SL_CMSRA_TREE T WHERE T.sl_tr_deleted_flag = 0 AND T.sl_tr_original_flag=1 AND T.sl_obj_id IN (772431, 995336, 993352, 989229, 992489, 1013935, 1036421, 994629, 993620, 994625, 935577, 994638, 989179, 935583, 935580, 1015555, 985308, 991465, 985153, 989345, 1040315, 935574, 992317, 802757, 935568, 802837, 989374, 994072, 777138, 989363, 802841, 989356)
2014-09-22 08:16:28,927 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-603 [Statement] - SELECT sl_tr_display_title, sl_obj_created_date, sl_obj_created_by, sl_tr_sortkey, sl_tr_parent, sl_tr_predecessor, sl_tr_successor, sl_tr_level, sl_tr_path, sl_tr_container_flag, sl_tr_container_type, T.sl_obj_id, sl_tr_splitnode_flag, sl_tr_original_flag, sl_tr_id FROM SL_CMSRA_TREE T, SL_CMSRA_OBJ O WHERE T.sl_obj_id = O.sl_obj_id AND T.sl_tr_deleted_flag = 0 AND T.sl_tr_id IN (985308, 802837, 1036421, 935577, 1040315, 935574, 994638, 991465, 989363, 772431, 989229, 989345, 802841, 1015555, 1013935, 992489, 777138, 985153, 994625, 994629, 994072, 935583, 989374, 992317, 993352, 935568, 935580, 993620, 995336, 989179, 802757, 989356)
2014-09-22 08:16:28,947 DEBUG gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-603 [PreparedStatement] - SELECT T.sl_tr_id, T.sl_tr_container_flag, sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_wfst_id, sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_check_out_flag, sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_link_indicator, sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_objtyp_id, '0', '1', sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_check_out_by, sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_content_flag, sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_reuse_flag, T.sl_tr_splitnode_flag, sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_note_flag, T.sl_obj_id, P.sl_tr_path, 3 AS slma_pp_id, VS.sl_vs_id, NVL(VS.sl_vs_state,'-'), NVL(VS.sl_vs_label,'-'), t.sl_tr_display_title, sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_last_changed_date, sl_CMSRA_common.language, sl_CMSRA_workflow.workflow_status, sl_CMSRA_cont.productserieskey, sl_CMSRA_versionset.sl_vs_label, sl_CMSRA_versionset.sl_vs_state, sl_CMSRA_cont.techctr, sl_CMSRA_cont.prodareas, sl_CMSRA_cont.appgroup, sl_CMSRA_series.appseries, sl_CMSRA_obj_objtype.SLMA_OBJTYP_DISPLAY_TITLE, sl_CMSRA_media.mediatype, sl_CMSRA_modules.infoclass, sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_last_changed_by, sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_check_out_by, sl_CMSRA_cont.projectname, sl_CMSRA_cont.description, sl_CMSRA_cont.duedate, sl_CMSRA_modules.tbdeleted FROM sl_CMSRA_obj_objtype, sl_CMSRA_media, sl_CMSRA_tree T, sl_versionset VS, sl_CMSRA_obj, sl_CMSRA_workflow, sl_CMSRA_common, sl_CMSRA_modules, sl_CMSRA_tree P, sl_CMSRA_versionset, sl_CMSRA_series, sl_CMSRA_cont WHERE P.sl_tr_id(+)=T.sl_tr_parent AND sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_id=T.sl_obj_id AND T.sl_tr_deleted_flag=0 AND sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_deleted_flag=0 AND VS.sl_obj_id(+)=sl_CMSRA_obj.sl_obj_id   AND sl_CMSRA_obj_objtype.sl_obj_id(+)=T.sl_obj_id  AND sl_CMSRA_media.sl_obj_id(+)=T.sl_obj_id  AND sl_CMSRA_workflow.sl_obj_id(+)=T.sl_obj_id  AND sl_CMSRA_common.sl_obj_id(+)=T.sl_obj_id  AND sl_CMSRA_modules.sl_obj_id(+)=T.sl_obj_id  AND sl_CMSRA_versionset.sl_obj_id(+)=T.sl_obj_id  AND sl_CMSRA_series.sl_obj_id(+)=T.sl_obj_id  AND sl_CMSRA_cont.sl_obj_id(+)=T.sl_obj_id AND T.sl_tr_id IN (772431, 995336, 993352, 989229, 992489, 1013935, 1036421, 994629, 993620, 994625, 935577, 994638, 989179, 935583, 935580, 1015555, 985308, 991465, 985153, 989345, 1040315, 935574, 992317, 802757, 935568, 802837, 989374, 994072, 777138, 989363, 802841, 989356) ORDER BY T.sl_tr_sibling_order -- []
2014-09-22 08:16:29,383 INFO gaissmaier@10.128.24.129-603 [DatabaseConnectionImpl] - performing commit
```

Comment: use `\(` for grouping in sed not `(`, `\{` four counting and structure is `s/search/replace/option`, you don't have Replace pattern someting like`\2` in this case (end should be `/\2/`g`). `m`option is not used here, sed work line per line by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -n 's/^[0-9-]\{10\} \([0-9,:]\{1,\}\) .*/\1/p' YourFile
```

posix version (`--posix`) for GNU sed

**explaination**

- `n` print content only with `p` action (so nothing else)
- `s///` for substition (used for a delete of unwanted info in this case)
- `^[0-9-]\{10\}` take the first group starting from 1st char and using only digit and `-` and including first space char. It is also keep in memory as 1st group (`\(...\)`)
- `\([0-9,:]\{1,\}\)` is our elected info, so second group based on digit, `,`and `:` (at least 1 char ) ant taking the biggest possible
- `.*`is taking the fllowing next space char + rest of the line
- `\1` substitute by content of first group (the only group in search pattern)
- `p` print option if substitution occur (so nothing on line that does not corrspond to the search pattern)

Comment: Thank you! It fits with my explanations. But could you please tell me the regex in more detailed, i mean how it works actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/{print $2}' file
18:26:59,300
18:26:59,301
18:26:59,301
18:26:59,301
18:26:59,301
18:26:59,824
18:26:59,824
18:26:59,824
18:26:59,967
18:26:59,967
18:26:59,967
18:26:59,968
18:26:59,968
18:27:00,479
18:27:00,479
18:27:00,479
18:27:00,482
```

Comment: Could you please try it the second log entry which i added. It gives an error message on this log.

Comment: I am not getting any error on 2nd log file and getting all correct output from `08:16:28,042` to `08:16:29,383`

Comment: Hmm, then the problem is related to my sed version. It appears that it is older than yours.

Comment: But I didn't give you any sed command. Mine is awk command. Also provide exact error you're getting.

Comment: Sorry for confusion i meant the awk command, awk: record `2014-09-22 08:16:28,...' has too many fields
 record number 1464 i saw this error message so i added the 08:16:28 lines of log file.

Comment: Most likely you have very old awk version.